# plt.matshow or imshow, how to scale the height individually

Tags: matplotlib

I have a plt.matshow() for the MFCC feature extraction. But since I have more resolutions in the x-axis than y-axis, the image appears very flat or skinny. Is there a way to scale the height individually to create a more square image view.

```
plt.figure()
ax = plt.gca()

im = ax.matshow(feat1.T,  cmap=plt.get_cmap('inferno'), origin='lower')
divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="3%", pad=0.05)
ax.xaxis.tick_bottom()
_ = plt.colorbar(im, cax=cax)
```

[image]

Comment: `ax.set_aspect(10)`. To get a perfect square, use `ax.set_aspect(72/12)` where 72 is the length of the x's and 12 of the y's.

Comment: setting it leaves a long gap between the matshow and colorbar, any suggestion to make colorbar closer. ?

Comment: Did you call `ax.set_aspect` just after `imshow` and before `make_axes_locatable` ? Apart from that, using `plt.colorbar(im)` and forgetting about the divider seems to work just fine.

Comment: Doing so seems to be the same, with the image being very small and colorbar very big. But setting aspect to 'auto' in matshow() seems to work very well.